# I can't install python3-pip?

Tags: kali-linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to install pip3 and this happend with me

```
┌──(rootDESKTOP-LUEK8HJ)-[/tmp]
└─# apt install python3-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python : Depends: libpython-stdlib (= 2.7.9-1) but it is not going to be installed
 python2 : PreDepends: python2-minimal (= 2.7.18-2) but it is not going to be installed
           Breaks: python (< 2.7.15-2) but 2.7.9-1 is to be installed
 python3-pip : Depends: python-pip-whl (= 18.1-5) but 20.1.1-2 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

i tried `apt --fix-broken install`

```
┌──(rootDESKTOP-LUEK8HJ)-[/tmp]
└─# apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cython3 fonts-roboto-slab forensic-artifacts freetds-common gdal-data gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 gir1.2-soup-2.4 gir1.2-vte-2.91
  gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 libaec0 libapache2-mod-php libarmadillo10 libarpack2 libblosc1 libcfitsio9 libcharls2 libdap25 libdapclient6v5
  libepsilon1 libfreexl1 libfyba0 libgdal28 libgeos-3.9.0 libgeos-c1v5 libgeotiff5 libhdf4-0-alt libhdf5-103-1 libhdf5-hl-100
  libjs-skeleton libkmlbase1 libkmldom1 libkmlengine1 libnetcdf18 libogdi4.1 libproj19 libpython-dev libpython2.7 libpython2.7-dev
  libqhull8.0 librttopo1 libspatialite7 libssl1.0.0 libsuperlu5 libsybdb5 libsz2 liburiparser1 libxerces-c3.2 node-normalize.css odbcinst
  odbcinst1debian2 pgcli proj-bin proj-data pwgen python-babel-localedata python-mpltoolkits.basemap-data python-odf-doc python-odf-tools
  python-pastedeploy-tpl python-pip-whl python-tables-data python2.7-dev python3-acora python3-adblockparser python3-advancedhttpserver
  python3-aiocmd python3-aioconsole python3-aiodns python3-aiomultiprocess python3-aiosqlite python3-aiowinreg python3-alembic
  python3-aniso8601 python3-apispec python3-apispec-webframeworks python3-appdirs python3-arrow python3-artifacts python3-asciitree
  python3-async-timeout python3-asysocks python3-autobahn python3-babel python3-boltons python3-bottle python3-bottleneck
  python3-cairo-dev python3-cbor python3-cherrypy3 python3-click-plugins python3-configobj python3-defusedxml python3-deprecation
  python3-dicttoxml python3-distro python3-django python3-docx python3-ecdsa python3-editor python3-email-validator python3-et-xmlfile
  python3-exif python3-exifread python3-expiringdict python3-feedparser python3-filedepot python3-filteralchemy python3-flasgger
  python3-flask-babelex python3-flask-classful python3-flask-kvsession python3-flask-login python3-flask-mail python3-flask-principal
  python3-flask-restful python3-flask-security python3-flask-sqlalchemy python3-flaskext.wtf python3-gdal python3-geoip python3-geojson
  python3-graphene python3-graphene-sqlalchemy python3-graphql-core python3-graphql-relay python3-hiredis python3-html2text
  python3-humanize python3-hupper python3-icalendar python3-icu python3-intervaltree python3-ipwhois python3-isodate python3-jdcal
  python3-jsonschema python3-jupyter-core python3-lsassy python3-marshmallow python3-marshmallow-sqlalchemy python3-maxminddb
  python3-minidump python3-minikerberos python3-mistune python3-mpltoolkits.basemap python3-msldap python3-multidict python3-nbformat
  python3-neo4j python3-neobolt python3-neotime python3-networkx python3-nplusone python3-ntlm-auth python3-numexpr python3-odf
  python3-openpyxl python3-pandas python3-pandas-lib python3-parsedatetime python3-paste python3-pastedeploy python3-pastescript
  python3-pgspecial python3-phonenumbers python3-plaster python3-plaster-pastedeploy python3-png python3-pptx python3-promise
  python3-psutil python3-pyaff4 python3-pycares python3-pydot python3-pyee python3-pyelftools python3-pygeoip python3-pygraphviz
  python3-pylnk python3-pymssql python3-pyotp python3-pypdf2 python3-pyppeteer python3-pyproj python3-pypykatz python3-pyqrcode
  python3-pyramid python3-pyrsistent python3-pyshp python3-pywerview python3-qrcode python3-rdflib python3-redis python3-rekall-core
  python3-rekall-lib python3-repoze.lru python3-retrying python3-routes python3-rq python3-rule-engine python3-rx python3-secure
  python3-selenium python3-setproctitle python3-simplekv python3-singledispatch python3-snappy python3-sparqlwrapper python3-speaklater
  python3-sqlalchemy python3-sqlalchemy-ext python3-sqlalchemy-schemadisplay python3-sqlparse python3-stem
  python3-syslog-rfc5424-formatter python3-tables python3-tables-lib python3-tempita python3-terminaltables python3-texttable python3-tld
  python3-tqdm python3-translationstring python3-trie python3-tsk python3-txaio python3-tz python3-tzlocal python3-u-msgpack
  python3-ubjson python3-unicodecsv python3-unidecode python3-uvloop python3-venusian python3-webargs python3-webob python3-websocket
  python3-wheel python3-whois python3-winacl python3-wsaccel python3-wtforms python3-xlsxwriter python3-xlwt python3-xmltodict
  python3-yarl python3-yaswfp python3-zope.deprecation xcape
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  python python-chardet python-colorama python-distlib python-enum34 python-idna python-ipaddress python-pkg-resources python-pyasn1
  python-setuptools python-wheel python2
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 12 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 5,210 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
(Reading database ... 333774 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing python-pyasn1 (0.1.7-1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-pyasn1.prerm: 6: pyclean: not found
dpkg: error processing package python-pyasn1 (--remove):
 installed python-pyasn1 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-pyasn1.postinst: 6: pycompile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed python-pyasn1 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-pyasn1
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

i tried `sudo apt autoremove` and `sudo apt-get purge python-chardet python-colorama python-distlib python-django python-django-tables2 python-six python-html5lib python-lxml python-minimal python-pkg-resources python-setuptools python-urllib3 python-requests python-pip python-virtualenv`

```
┌──(rootDESKTOP-LUEK8HJ)-[/tmp]
└─# sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python : Depends: libpython-stdlib (= 2.7.9-1) but it is not installed
 python2 : PreDepends: python2-minimal (= 2.7.18-2) but it is not installed
           Breaks: python (< 2.7.15-2) but 2.7.9-1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

does anyone countered the same problem?

Comment: yes it is kali on wsl

Comment: how can i fix this problem i tried to remove python2 but it didn't get removed i tried also to replace pyclean.py but it didn't work

Comment: I just deleted my earlier comment by accident. Kali is not normally a system where you keep lots of data, so that it should be easier to just reinstall it rather than trying to recover from a broken package database. I just installed Kali from the Microsoft store, `apt update`, then `apt install python3-pip` without a hitch.

Comment: yeah you are right it doesn't worth it